# can I protect my computer with multiple user accounts?

Tags: windows-7, virus, user-accounts

I used to spend most of my time downloading things off the internet until I got viruses in my computer(tons) So I had to redo my computer. I am playing it smart this time and I'm more careful in what I do. Just recently I was structed with a question I just have to ask, it may sound obvious but here it goes.

I was thinking of making two user accounts, account A and account B, account A would be used for school work and important matter. and account B with other things. If I use account B and get a virus in it will it effect account A? Also will I be able to get rid of the virus if I simply delete account B?

my operating system is windows 7.

Thanks​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the account B is a Limited Account, They your system files might not be accessible by viruses, but they might be the least of worries if the rest of the computer is infected. As both accounts will have access to the filesystem, if a virus accesses one of your drives, both accounts will get infected.

Comment: Well, I knew it wouldn't be pretty but thanks for the info.